# Manage different classes MonoGame XNA,

Tags: xna, monogame

I'm making a game in MonoGame with several states. It is very complicated to manage all this in the same class. Is there a way to divide these states with different objects and properties between different classes? 
I want to manage the same modules: Draw, Update, load content but focused on other states of the game.

Comment: It's difficult to understand this without code, what looks compilated to you? Could you show a portion of the code that explains the problem properly? Classes are mostly useful if the code is mostly focussed about a single object. So I wonder if that can be used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If by different states you mean something like different game screens (menus, main game screens, maps) you can create a game screen class which then contains the functionality required for the current state and overrides Draw, Update etc methods. You can create a different game screen for every map or just one map screen which then loads the map externally etc.

Then create a class to manage current game screens which has methods for changing active game screen (creating new instances by activator and setting it as current screen object) and calling the current screens update & draw methods via override. The main game loop will then call the screen manager without having to worry about knowing the current state.

I found this particular tutorial series to be really helpful since it explains on how to create game screens, screen managers etc: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agt9-J9RPZ0 (C# Monogame RPG Made Easy Tutorial by CodingMadeEasy).